# LINQ query not statisfying the datetime validation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, linq-to-sql, razor-pages

This is my LINQ for returning the matching record

```
var staffawards = await _context.StaffAwards.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.StaffID == StaffAwards.StaffID && c.EmpID == StaffAwards.EmpID && c.AwardDate == StaffAwards.AwardDate);
```

The StaffAwards.AwardDate will be in this format "09/12/2020 12:00:00 AM"
whereas the AwardDate in my table will be like this "2020-12-09 17:16:00.000"

How can i convert the StaffAwards.AwardDate in Sql Server datetime?
AnyHelp would be appreciated.

Comment: 1 Don't confuse date/time string representation with real storage format: neither .NET, nor SQL Server store date/time as strings. What you have posted is the string representation. 2. What field type is used for `AwardDate`? 3. Do you really need to compare date/time, or dates comparison will be enough?

Comment: Both SQL Server and C# have a native DateTime type (SQL Server has other time and date types). Those types don't have a format unless you convert them to a string (in which case, you can convert them to any format). If your `StaffAwards.AwardDate` is a string, convert it to a DateTime using Parse or TryParse (or their *Exact* equivalents

Comment: Hi @Dennis ,the datatype for StaffAwards.AwardDate is Datetime,since im using datetimepicker the input field type is given as Text. I just want to check whether the table value is equal to the userinput value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code and your database use Date/DateTime types as they should be, and not strings then you need to understand a few things:

- date datatypes don't have a format, only strings created from dates have a format. Whatever format you see in your code/sql query tool is the formatting it has applied when it showed you the date (it had to turn it to a string to display it)
- a datetime with a time of midnight is a completely different datetime to one where the time is 17:16, just like a number 1.0 is a completely different number to 1.75352; you will never get a database to return you a record with a time of midnight if you use equals and pass a time of anything other than midnight, just like you will never succeed in getting a record where the age of the person is 1.0 by asking "where age = 1.75352"

Either fix up your parameter so it is midnight, like the db is, or use a parameter range (if the dates in the db will have times other than also)

```
//if the db date is always midnight
.Where(x => x.DateColumnInDb == datetimeParameter.Date);

//if the db might have times too
.Where(x => x.DateColumnInDb >= datetimeParameter.Date && x.DateColumnInDb < datetimeParameter.Date.AddDays(1));
```

By using a range, we do not risk asking the database to convert every datetime in the table, every time we want to query. Converting data in a where clause is typically a bad idea because it usually leads to significant performance loss because indexes cannot be used

Also, make sure your .net side datetime and your db time use the same timezone or they will actually be referring to different times

Comment: Hi @Caius Jard, Thank you so much for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

To use a Date with the Database-Format you can use the DbFunctions.

Like this:

```
var staffawards = await _context.StaffAwards.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.StaffID == StaffAwards.StaffID && c.EmpID == StaffAwards.EmpID && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Parse(c.AwardDate)) == StaffAwards.AwardDate);
```

Important: For TruncateTime, you have to use a DateTime. You have to convert c.AwardDate to DateTime. `DateTime.Parse(c.AwardDate)`

Comment: Hi @Presi,when im changing my query to yours it showing  'DbFunction doesnot contains a definition for TruncateTime' and also c.AwardDate iis also showing some errors like 'Argument 1:Cannot convert form System.Datetime to System.ReadOnlySpan'

Comment: Do you have the `using System.Data.Entity;` in your code? Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have the SQL server installed on a separate machine, which may be due to a different date format.

But there is no need for this conversion, the entity framework will do it automatically for you.
If you just compare date, you can use this code :

```
var staffawards = await _context.StaffAwards.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.StaffID == StaffAwards.StaffID && c.EmpID == StaffAwards.EmpID && c.AwardDate.Date == StaffAwards.AwardDate.Date);
```

Comment: Hi @Ramil Aliyev, Currently the sql query executing is showing like this - SELECT * FROM StaffAwards Where StaffID='19' AND EmpID='12345678' AND AwardDate='09/12/2020 12:00:00 AM' - which is returning an empty resultset.

Comment: i executed the same query in SSMS with the some changes - SELECT * FROM StaffAwards Where StaffID='19' AND EmpID='12345678' AND AwardDate='2020-12-09 17:16:00.000' - this will out one record

Comment: @Teena Is the AwardDate column type datetime or nvarchar in the database ?

Comment: Hi @Ramil Aliyev,the colum type is datetime